# How to create pie chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, charts, pie-chart

new to Python and stuck with a pie chart.
Apologies for the complexity but I am at a lost as how to proceed ..
I  have this  dataset in the form of a dictionary (part of it)

```
{'Deaths5': 94, 'Deaths10': 379, 'Deaths12': 388, 'Deaths8': 138, 'Deaths25': None,
 'IM_Deaths2': None, 'Deaths14': 511, 'Deaths1': 20535, 'Deaths23': 2643, 'Deaths6': 62,
 'IM_Deaths1': 4349, 'Deaths17': 1036, 'Deaths18': 1234, 'Sex': '2', 'Deaths11': 358, 'Deaths22': 1708,
 'Deaths21': 1922, 'IM_Frmat': '08', 'SubDiv': '', 'Deaths15': 600, 'Deaths4': 157, 'Admin1': '',
 'IM_Deaths3': None, 'Deaths19': 1125, 'Deaths24': None, 'Frmat': '01', 'Deaths20': 1602, 'Deaths3': 350,
 'Year': '1964', 'Deaths7': 149, 'Deaths9': 311, 'Deaths26': 33, 'Country': '2150',
 'Deaths16': 932, 'Deaths13': 454, 'Deaths2': 4349, 'IM_Deaths4': None, 'Cause': 'A000', 'List': '07A' .......
```

I need to generate a pie chart that shows the latest year - 2013,
and shows the top 8 causes of death code 'Cause' from field 'Deaths1'

So to sum it up:

So for example  the data should be filtered as

```
Year    CAUSE    Top8
2013     A000    5000
2013     A411    400
2013     A50     200
.....
```

and then shown as a pie chart with anything after the top 8 treated as 'other'

I could do this very easily with SQL but with Python...I am not sure.

Comment: Why is high charts a tag? Different programming language yeah?

Comment: sorry it should say list /dictionary not a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Seaborn's` Pie Plot. Let's see an example of how pie plot was used to visualize the famous Iris flower data.

All you have to do is to import the library and play around with it:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

For starters, here's the dataset's top 5 rows retrieved by the `head()` method:
[image]

The dataset has 3 classes:
[image]

Now, I wanted to plot the classes as pie chart

```
dataset['Class'].value_counts().plot.pie(explode=[0.05, 0.05,0.05], autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, figsize=(8,8))
plt.title('Pie Chart for Class')
plt.show()
```

And voila!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Full disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

You can use [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/) for free to accomplish this. I'm not sure if you were looking for the answer to include how to parse the dictionary or just the data visualization portion. With some simple attributes we can display the data in a legible manner. From there we can hover nodes to get more information about the node and we can click on the legend to remove a node from the graph. This will re calculate the percentage taken up be each node amongst remaining, non hidden nodes.

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: 'pie',
  title:{
    text: '2013 Deaths',
    adjustlayout: true
  },
  legend:{
    toggleAction: 'remove'
  },
  plot:{
    valueBox:{ // hard label
      placement:'out'
    }
  },
  tooltip:{ // for node hover
    text:'%t: Had %v deaths in 2013'
  },
 series: [
  {
   values: [5000],
   text: 'A000'
  },
  {
   values: [400],
   text: 'A411'
  },
  {
   values: [200],
   text: 'A00'
  },
  {
   values: [900],
   text: 'Other'
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
  ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9","ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];</script>
 <!--Inject End-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm sorry I did not post a solution within python. You can downvote the answer. The only python solution I have is through our online demos repo.

https://github.com/zingchart-demos/python-django

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html) for creating Pie charts in Python

Example Pie Chart:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
sizes = [40, 20, 20, 20]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title('Year 2013')
plt.show()
```